# Scroll Webview with RadialController while getting RotationChanged event

Tags: c#, webview, uwp

I'm using a Surface Dial to scroll a WebView in a UWP application. I'd like to grab the RotationChanged event of the RadialController class while the scrolling function is being preserved.

However, to get the RotationChanged event I currently have to add a new RadialControllerMenuItem and select it after the app launched before I get any events. When I do this, the WebView wont scroll as it did before.

Is it even possible to do this at the same time?

Comment: No, it is not possible. The WebView handles all manipulations and scroll events itself.

Comment: I want the WebView to handle those events. I just want to know what the dial is doing. Is there no way to get that?

Comment: No. Unfortunately you can't handle any events when the WebView is handling them.

Comment: A workaround would be to handle the scroll event in JavaScript and pass the data to the app. window.onscroll Event: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onscroll.asp
Pass data to app: https://www.suchan.cz/2016/01/hacking-uwp-webview-part-2-bypassing-window-external-notify-whitelist/

Comment: I was thinking it might be easier to scroll the page using JavaScript instead of trying to get the info back from the WebView. Will try both I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up triggering a keydown-Event inside the WebView which works nicely in my scenario. The site then reacts to the event using jQuery.

```
string script = "var e = $.Event('keydown'); e.which = 40; $('body').trigger(e);"
string[] scriptArgs = { script };
await WebView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", scriptArgs);
```